# webkit border radius question

Tags: overlay, css

Here's my problem: I'm showing an overlay (using [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html)) with a message div that has rounded corners.

Here is my css code for message div:

```
#modal1
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: none;
    width: 620px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;

    border: 12px solid #FF771C;  
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;

    text-align: center;
}
```

And my problem is that I get a white "border" (if you look closely) in the upper left and right corners. [Here is the image](http://mnrjecnik.com/slike/overlay.png) so you can see for yourself. Now, I "solved" this by putting top-left and -right border properties of webkit to 0px, but this is not a solution, so I'm asking if you have maybe some ideas? Btw, this is only developed for chrome that's why it's only -webkit up there in the code..

**EDIT:**
I found the solution on their forum http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/40/46850

Comment: you can just write: `border-radius: 12px;` instead of your four lines. The -webkit- prefix is also no longer needed for Chrome, I'm not sure about Safari.

Comment: @Bazz: yes, that works, but I still have that white border as mentioned above in the question

Comment: What happens if you remove that `border: 12px solid #FF771C;` ? Does border-ish thing goes away?

Comment: @nikola Then it has to be something behind your `#modal1` - Regarding `-webkit` prefix: It is kinda hard to believe, but `-webkit-border-radius` may behave differently than regular `border-radius` so you might want to give it a try and removing vendor prefix. Here is an article mentioning it [link](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/how-avoid-common-css3-mistakes)

Comment: @vlad: yes, i think it is something to do with the plugin I'm using for modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be the border of another div or element behind your rounded bordered div

Comment: @Unmair: yes, you were right, though I couldn't find what exactly and then I found that the flowplayer overlay plugin used some sort of image which wasn't on my server and that's what was under my div. Anyway, I found a solution here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/40/46850

Comment: I am glad that was of Help. the Name is Umair btw :)